# Structure Packing

Tags: structure, packing

I'm currently learning C# and my first project (as a learning experiment) is to create a DBF reader. I'm having some difficulty understanding "packing" according to this: [http://www.developerfusion.com/pix/articleimages/dec05/structs1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxyvD.jpg)

If I specified a packing of 2, wouldn't all structure elements begin on a 2-byte boundary, and if I specified a packing of 4, wouldn't all structure elements begin on a 4-byte boundary, and also consume a minimum of 4 bytes each?

For instance, a `byte` element would be placed on a 4 byte boundary, and the element following it (in a sequential layout) would be located on the next 4-byte boundary (losing 3 bytes to padding)?

In the image shown, in the "pack=4" it shows a `byte` that is on a 2 byte boundary, following a `short`.

Comment: Are you just curious about how much space the different items take up?  If you're just learning C# you'll find that you don't need to worry so much about memory management like you did in C++.  C# does a lot more things automatically for you.

Comment: I'm reading from a file that has a specific packing that is different from the standard packing of C#. I'm reading the elements just fine using a packing of 1, but now I'm confused as to how these other packing schemes are working.

I think I'm understanding it that it will literally "pack" all elements that will fit within that space up to the next element. So 4 sequential byte elements will pack contiguously, or one short and 2 bytes, or two shorts.

Comment: Not an answer, but there is very little reason to use struct packing if you're implementing any sort of binary reader. This is common practice in C to squeeze out performance, but even there it's hard to get it right in a portable fashion (and most programmers don't get it right). In C# there's even less reason as you'll be operating on byte arrays rather than memory directly. You can use `BitConverter` to convert bytes into fields in a way that doesn't depend on matching up bytes in the file with bytes in memory.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I'm trying to avoid extra abstraction to minimize the objects involved, but I'm still interested in the methodology (for learning purposes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the picture correctly, pack equal to `n` means that one variable cannot be stored "between" two packs of lengths `n`. In other words, bytes which compose a variable cannot cross one pack's boundary. This is only true if the size of a variable is less or equal to the size of a pack.

Let's take `Pack = 4` as an example. Here, we can safely store a byte and a short in one pack, because they require 3 bytes of memory together. But since there is only one byte in the pack left, it requires one byte of padding to be able to store an int into the data structure, because what's left in the pack is too little to store the whole int.

I hope the explanation makes sense.

Looking at the picture again, I think it would be better if all data were aligned to the same side of a pack, either to bottom or top. This would make it clearer what's going on.